# Downloaded file not opening in correct format

Tags: php

I have two php files
 1. List_files ->show all uploaded files
 2. Get_file ->to download files from listed files...

Now when i download any image or any text document and try to open it it is not getting opened,

Error is format not supported everytime.

My image is .jpeg

I am using Windows Vista with Firefox.
No problem in downloading, problem is in opening the file..

```
get_file.php

<?php
                                                                        // Make sure an ID was passed
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) 
    {
                                                                      // Get the ID
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);

                                                                   // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
        if($id <= 0)  
        {
            die('The ID is invalid!');
        }
       else 
        {
                                                              // Connect to the database
           $con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

                if(!$con)
                {
                    die('Could Not Connect:'.mysql_error());
                }    

                mysql_select_db("tcs",$con);

                                                                                                        // Fetch the file information
           $query = "SELECT `mime`, `name`, `size`, `data` FROM `file` WHERE `id` = {$id}";
           $result=mysql_query($query,$con);

           if($result) 
           {

                $count = mysql_num_rows($result);                                                           // Make sure the result is valid
                if($count == 1) 
                {
                                                                                        // Get the row
                   $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


                    // Print headers

                   header("Content-Type: ".$row['mime']);
                   header("Content-Length: ".$row['size']);
                   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['name']);

                   // Print data
                   echo $row['data'];
               }
               else 
               {
                   echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
               }

               // Free the mysqli resources
               //mysql_free_result($result);
           }
           else 
           {
               echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>".mysql_error()."</pre>";
           }
           mysql_close();
       }
   }
   else 
   {
       echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: You should show get_files instead of list_files here.

Comment: Did you try open files with Notepad? It happened to me, that instead content all that been saved were warnings and errors.

Comment: oh i am soory now i am showing the correct file

Answer (score 2):

You have posted the wrong file in your question, this is a list of files, but the problem most likely is in the other file, the `get_files.php`.

Most likely, you are not sending the "content-type" header.
If you say it is an JPEG image, then  it should read as

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
```

If you want it as a download (and not opening it in browser), you could add one more header

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=your_current_filename.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in `get_files.php`. Most likely it does not set a correct [content-type header](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1521/4.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is in this: `header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$row['name']);` Filenames are restricted to `US-ASCII` and should not contain spaces. So you might need to do some cleanup on the filename. (Some people do use spaces, and enclose the filename in quotation marks. This works, but it's non-standard.)

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt

Comment: where i have given spaces will u plz edit the code or tell writing that particular line where i am getting wrongi have not used spaces uin [].

Comment: I'm just saying that you should be careful sending back user-generated content (such as the filename) without sanitising it first. $row['name'] could be anything, couldn't it? So make sure it's US-ASCII with no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

add this to your headers

```
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
```

this might solve your problem.

Comment: Sometimes works, but is non-standard. The proper way to force a download is the Content-Disposition header.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. We need to do some debugging. Use a tool which shows you the actual PHP headers being sent. (I like Web-Sniffer.net. There are also some Firefox plugins which do this.)

Remove the Content-Length header: it's nice to have for progressive download bars, but it's unnecessary; and if it's wrong it could be buggering things up.

Remove the Content-Disposition header. See if the right file is being served at all.

Basically, check each small part of the code individually, before stitching it all together. That way, you have some idea where the bugs are.